Quotient map from a compactification to a n point compactification
Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space.
A compactification $c(X)$ of $X$ is a  compact Hausdorff space $c(X)$ paired with a map $i:X\to c(X)$ such that $i$ is an embedding and $i(X)\subseteq c(X)$ is dense.
A finite point compactification is a compactification $c(X)$ such that $c(X)-X$ is finite. In particular if $|c(X)-X|=n$, then $c(X)$ is called n-point compactification
A compactification map is a continuous quotient map $\pi:c_1(X)\to c_2(X)$ with $\pi|X=id_X$ (restriction to $X$) and $\pi(c(X)-X)=c_2(X)-X$.
I am trying to see two things.

If $c(X)$ is compactification that is not finite point and if $\hat{X}$ is an n point compactification, then there is compactification map $\pi:c(X)\to \hat{X}$

If $c_1(X)$ is an n-point compactification and $c_2(X)$ m-point compactification with $n>m$, then there is compactification map $\pi:c_1(X)\to c_2(X)$


In short, when X is locally compact, there is always a unique compactification to 1 point compactification from every (bigger) compactification, can this property extended to other finite point compactifications.

For the thing you describe in your very last sentence, check out this question & answer.

Both are false:
#1 is false: 
$\beta \mathbb N \setminus \mathbb N$ contains a countable infinite, discrete subset $E$.
Let $f: E \rightarrow [0,1] \cap \mathbb Q$ be a surjective map. By Gillman, Jerison, Rings of continuous functions, 6O,
$E$ is $C^\star$-embedded in $\beta \mathbb N$.
Hence, there is also a continuous extension
$f^\prime: \beta \mathbb N \setminus \mathbb N \rightarrow [0,1]$ of $f$. Hence, $f^\prime$ is surjective.
By Engelking, General topology, 3.5.13, $\mathbb N$ has a compactification $c(\mathbb N)$ with remainder homeomorphic to $[0, 1]$. Since this is connected, there is no compactification map to a 2-point compactification of $\mathbb N$.
#2 is false: 
Let $X = (0, 2) \setminus \{1\}$.
Then $[0,2]$ is a connected, 3-point compactification of $X$.
Moreover, $X$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R \oplus \mathbb R$. Hence, $S^1 \oplus S^1$ is a 2-point compactification of $X$.
Since the latter is not connected, there is no compactification map $[0,2] \rightarrow  S^1 \oplus S^1$.
Addendum to #1 
Here is an explicit construction of a compactification of $\mathbb N$ with remainder $[0,1]$:
Let $(F_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be an increasing sequence of finite sets such that
$ \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} F_n = 
   [0,1] \cap \mathbb Q$.

$D = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} (F_n \times \{\frac{1}{n}\}) \subset \mathbb R^2$
with the Euclidean topology
is countable infinite and discrete, hence homeomorphic to $\mathbb N$.
Moreover,
$\overline{D} = D \cup ([0,1] \times \{0\})$
is closed, bounded, hence compact.
Thus, $\overline{D}$ is a compactification of $D$ with remainder
$[0,1] \times \{0\}$.
